# Comboxbox Selected Value In XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, selectedvalue

How to set the selectedvalue for combobox. For example I have some values from 1-10 and I want to select the 5th value.

I tried using `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem`, but its not working for me.

Comment: Depends on how you are setting it, but anvaka's response should be correct based on what you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedIndex should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select "the fifth value", you should use SelectedIndex = 4 (since indexes are zero-based). If you want to select "the value 5", you should use SelectedValue = 5.

Comment: i just gave an example that i have some values from 1-10 and i want to select the 5th value.

i have dynamic data..

Answer (score 0):

A ComboBox in WPF can select items in 3 ways.
The first is to set SelectedIndex, where you set the zero-based index to an item.
Another way is to to set a value with SelectedValue. Here you must add the value of the object you have selected. F.e. you have 3 comboboxitems {hello, bye, good morning}. So lets say you want to select bye you have to set SelectedValue = "bye".
The last way ist to set the selected object by SelectedItem. There you have to set an ComboBoxItem or an XmlElement. You have to know that a combobox can contain ComboBoxItems and XmlElements. The behaviour is a bit differnt, but if you work with combobox some time you will understand it.

Hope this helps.